# Flutter UI doesn't update - search in gridView

Tags: flutter, search, state

I have a GridView.builder widget displaying all of the users of the app from the list searchedUsers and I am trying to implement searching. The TextFormField widget's onChanged property is defined to trigger the searchName(String searchQuery) function. I made the searchName function print out the searchedUsers list and I can see from the log that it is updated everytime I type something in the TextFormField but the GridView is always empty. Please see the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have added comments to the code to explain everything.

```
class UserGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserGridState createState() => _UserGridState();
}

class _UserGridState extends State<UserGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    //The list of userModels from FireStore
    final userModels = Provider.of<List<UserModel>>(context) ?? [];

    //The list that will contain users whose names match the value in TextFormField
    List<UserModel> searchedUsers = [];

    //The function that updates the searchedUsers list. I wrote setState whenever I changed the 
    //list because I thought it would update the UI but it doesn't

    void searchName (String searchQuery){
      for (var i in userModels) {
        if (i.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            searchedUsers.add(i);
            print(searchedUsers);
          });
        }
      }
      if (searchedUsers == null) {
        setState(() {

          searchedUsers = userModels;
        });
      }
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 20,),

        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(1000.0),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        searchName(val);
                      },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusColor: Colors.white,
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          labelText: 'For- eller efternavn',
                        ))))),

        SizedBox(height: 40,),

        GridView.builder(
              itemCount: searchedUsers.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return userModelTile(userModel: searchedUsers[index]);
                },
            ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The list searchedUsers need to be defined before the build function.